# Validating a truststore against a keystore in one step

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, pki, pfx

I have a .p12 keystore and a .jks truststore.

Is there an easy way (possibly with a script or a 3rd party software) to verify whether they are valid and matching ?

Answer (score 0):

Just transform the PKCS#12 one to a JKS one with the `keytool` and compare the binary files.